# How can I turn the focus off when a new input type is added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I turn the focus off when a new inpu is added? I want to do this because when i am on my iPad and press "Add Field" it automatically brings up the keyboard. This is very annoying because sometimes I want to add a few new input fields before entering data.

```js
  $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
   var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
   $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
   });
   $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
     $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" style="height:50px;">
 <input type="submit" name="stocksave" value="Save" class="float" style = "float:right;">  
 </br></br>
  
   <div class="multi-field-wrapper focusoff">
   
   <div class="multi-fields focusoff">
   <div class="multi-field focusoff">
   <input type="text" name="stockitem[]" autocomplete="off" class="focusoff">
   <select name='piecesdd[]' style='width:150px; '>
   
      <option value='0'>PIECES</option>
      <?php
      $count = 1;
      while ($count<=100) {
     echo "<option value='".$count."'>".$count."</option>";
     $count++;
      };
      ?>
   </select>
   <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
   
   <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
   
   </div>
    
   </div>
     
 </div>
 
  
</form>
```

Comment: You don't want to focus new added element then?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.focus()` from below line on `.add-field` - `click event`

```
$('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper)
.find('input').val('').focus()
```

So it would be just

```
$('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper)
.find('input').val('')
```

Comment: I hope this isn't the answer (even i understand it like this too) because it would be a silly question, isn't it? :)

Comment: Yea, Agreed, but if the OP isn't aware that there is `.focus` at the end then, definitely he has to see this :).. @A.Wolff

Comment: This has solved my issue.... sorry this seemed a simple question to you but iv been messing around with the focus in css for ages. Thank you BTW @A.Wolff

Comment: @elliestone, Also You can visit **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)** to see whether user is on device and keep/remove the `focus` accordingly.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Ya good point, OP would want not focusing element only on specifc device

Comment: @elliestone Don't worry, glad you have fixed it